# Memory usage keeps increasing

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-leaks

I've created a pretty simple test app. It includes a 3 view controllers. The main view controller has a table view, that uses custom cells. The other two view controllers are able to be accessed through the main view controller, each have collection views, and can go back to the main view controller.

Here is the memory issue. Anytime I click on any of the cells from the 3 view controllers, the memory usage increases. I ran the app while using the 'Leaks' profiling template and found no leaks. Also used the 'Allocations' profiling template, checked 2 of the view controllers (recorded the reference counts), and all the stored reference counts under my program were released.

I haven't been able to use the Debug Memory Graph as it keeps crashing Xcode...

Main View Controller

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchForTool: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolTable: UITableView!

    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var data = ["  Alphabetical", "  Numerical"]
    var identities = ["A", "B"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        toolTable.delegate = self
        toolTable.dataSource = self
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.toolLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

One of the other View Controllers (both identical)

```
import UIKit

class AlphabeticalViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var labelArray = [String]()
    var identities = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        labelArray = ["Main", "Definitions", "Steps", "References", "Other"]

        identities = ["C", "B", "B", "D", "E"]

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labelArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let myLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        myLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Custom Cell Class

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I will provide any other images if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Information I got using the allocation tool.
[image: Possible Memory Leak]
The commented out code is just a search feature that I don't need atm.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: One thing I recommend you to try is add `deinit` into all suspicious classes so you can check they are deallocated for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the indentation edit (mine was a bit rushed). I'll go ahead and see if that helps narrow down the issue.

Comment: When you navigate back to the main view controller is the memory released? If you keep navigating forwards then the memory won't release the view controllers you have navigated from.

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I'll put another important piece of information I just got. Might help. I'll see if I can figure out about what you're saying.

Comment: @totiG so I checked the AlphabeticalViewController (2nd set of code above) and checked that the reference counter both retained and released from 'didSelectRowAt' func. That's where my navigation code is between the ViewControllers. So I'm guessing that's not the problem.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but I am running xcode from a virtual machine. Not sure if this would cause this type of problem, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @totiG, you're right! I keep pushing view controllers on to the navigation stack, but never pop them out. All I need now is a way to look at the previous index and remove it from the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I want to give credit to @totiG for pointing out that the problem could be with the navigation controller, and he was right.

There are other smaller memory issues, but the biggest by far had to do with my navigation. I kept pushing controllers onto the navigation stack, without popping them.

Here is the code for my final solution.

I replaced:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

}
```

With:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            for controller in navController.viewControllers {
                if controller is TableViewController {
                    navController.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {

        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

So now instead of pushing from controller to controller without popping any of them off of the stack, I pop all of the previous controllers up to the 'TableViewController' when 'Main' is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be inside the `CustomCell`, maybe some resources not deinitialized.
Do you have some code inside `awakeFromNib()` or `setSelected(...)`?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I don't have any code in either. I think the use of CustomCell from the TableView func cellForRowAt is somehow the problem.. not sure tho.

Comment: What Khalid says seems correct, you're using TableViewController so you don't have to use an @IBOutlet (and also delegate and datasource are not required). On the other side on the AlphabeticalViewController they are required because you are not using a CollectionViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your tableView and collection view. look at IBOutlets your tableView name is toolTable

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolTable: UITableView!
```

but inside your datasource for the tableView you're accessing the wrong tableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // this is the wrong tableView
    /*
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    */
    // you should use the tableview which you have declared 
    let cell = toolTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.toolLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

You have the same problem with your CollectionViewControllers as well.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //accessing wrong collectionView
    /*
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    */
    // here you have to use self because your have named your collectionView the same as collectionView
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let myLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    myLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Note: Your TableViewController and CollectionViewController are already  Controllers. wondering why you have another tableView and collection view  IBOutlets. Use one at a time

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes, and there might be a slight difference in the increase of memory. But it's still going up... still not 100% why.

Comment: @SlavictheSlavic as I mentioned in my answer you are using TableViewController and still you have a separate tableView which causes these problems I can not see your project so you have to fix that

Comment: I'll put up a screen shot of my storyboard to clear up any confusion. I don't really need the tableview delegate for the custom cells, but I did use it for the searchbar function (it's commented out, and not in the code provided above).

Comment: The tableView and collectionView given by the datasource is exactly the same as the one stored in your controllers, this won't change anything.